# CSS: Scroll with persistent header inside area with persistent header

Tags: css

I have a layout that has a header at the top. The header never moves. The content below scrolls

```
<div style="display: flex; height: 100%; flex-direction: column">
  <div>
     Header never moves 
  </div>
  <div style="flex: 1; overflow: auto">
     Internal scroll area 
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to put another* header within the scroll area that, similar to the last one, does not move.

```
<div style="display: flex; height: 100%; flex-direction: column">
  <div>
     Header never moves 
  </div>
  <div style="flex: 1; overflow: auto">
      <div style="display: flex; height: 100%; flex-direction: column">
         <div>
            Header never moves 
         </div>
         <div style="flex: 1; overflow: auto">
            Internal scroll area 
         </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The height 100% in the second/internal scroll area makes the scroll bar go beyond the bottom of the page in the internal scroll area. I need the internal scroll area to *only scroll within it's given height. Any ideas? I can't find an answer on this.

Comment: `height: 100%;` won't work, height is infinite, you need `height: 100vh;` and work from there

Comment: vh still seems to take the entire screen's height, not just the height of the given area

Comment: `height: 100%;`  doesn't make any sense anyway, What are you trying to do ?

Comment: trying to get the height of the internal div so it knows how far to scroll. It's obviously not 100% the height of the screen. So I need the height of the internal div. I know I could probably rig some crazy system with JS. But there must* be a way to do this with CSS

Comment: without height: 100%, overflow scrolling does not work

Comment: i was talking about the most outer div

Comment: The outermost div takes up the entire page's height. So it was needed (by another dev) to ensure scrolling in the outer section. The new layout requires another header inside the out scrolling area. This header is also supposed to persist.

Comment: something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/wetsgzv7/) ?

Comment: Except the red area can't be a fixed height like 900px. It has to take up the remaining height of the page.

Comment: I don't really understand the end result here, the red area is just to mimic long content to cause overflow.

Answer (score 1):

You should get rid of the `overflow: auto` of the element in line 5, and use `position: sticky` instead.

The `overflow: auto` of the div should do the job for the "Internal scroll area".

Playground: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-playground-r747zw

Example:

**html**

```html
<div style="display: flex; height: 100%; flex-direction: column">
  <div id="header-1">
     Header never moves 
  </div>
  <div class="inner-wp" style="flex: 1;">
      <div style="display: flex; height: 100%; flex-direction: column">
         <div id="header-2">
            Header never moves 
         </div>
         <div style="flex: 1; overflow: auto">
            Internal scroll area 
         </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```css
#header-1 {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0; /* mandatory */
}

#header-2 {
  position: sticky;
  top: 18px; /* mandatory. you need to adjust this depending on #header-1 and your case */
}
```

Comment: The header can crush and grow so a fixed height/top value won't work.

Comment: If your `#header-1` has a fixed size (which is most probably the case), then it doesn't matter what height the other header `#header-2` has. It should work in any case. If `#header-1` has a dynamic height too, then JavaScript comes into the play - this is why we have it, right? :-)